# Can I make a new clash of clans account on my old device?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I've been playing COC for about 2 years now. I upgraded my phone last week, I easily transfer my TH10 account on my new phone.

Now, I want to make a new account on my old phone but every time I download it, the old base is still appearing.

I did the reset settings in SETTING>GENERAL>RESET and nothing happened.
I also logged out my Game Center, iCloud, AppleID.. and create a new one but still every time I download Clash of Clans, my old account is still there.

What do I do next?

Comment: What device is this?  If you can spare the data loss, try a factory reset or uninstall the game from the device.

Comment: Look in /android/data or /android/obb in the case you have android and look whether there are remaining files after an uninstallation. Since you want to erase everything you can't mess up anything :)

Comment: Android or Apple?

Comment: you guys  read the question properly "I also logged out my Game Center, iCloud, AppleID"

Comment: i can't count how often this question gets asked here....

Answer (score 1):

Plug your phone into iTunes and do a complete restore not from a backup but a restore this will fix your problem as it did or me.

When you download clash of clans again use a iTunes account the has never downloaded or purchased clash of clans.

Answer (score 0):

If you go under Settings, then tap Apps, look for Clash of Clans.  Then when you have found it Uninstall it or Clear Data.

(If you cleared Data) run Clash of Clans then start your new Account, Be wary you can NOT have two Clash of Clans accounts linked with one Google Account.

(If you Uninstalled)  Install Clash of Clans then Run it.  You should end up with the Tutorial, Enjoy your new Account.  But be wary you can NOT have two Clash of Clans accounts linked with one Google Account.

---

If that doesn't work try going under settings and then go under Accounts and take your Account that is linked with your Clash of Clans base and Delete it off of your phone.  Then try the previous steps.